# Issue on Installing BootStrap 4.0.0-beta.2 using bower

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, bower-install

I executed the following command on Node

> bower install bootstrap#4.0.0-beta.2

and am getting the following error

```
bower not-cached    https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap.git#4.0.0-beta.2
bower resolve       https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap.git#4.0.0-beta.2
bower download      https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/archive/v4.0.0-beta.2.tar.gz
bower extract       bootstrap#4.0.0-beta.2 archive.tar.gz
bower EMALFORMED    Failed to read 
C:\Users\taddesee\AppData\Local\Temp\ALPHA-
taddesee\bower\ca4c50b905dc21ea17a10549a6f5944f-14096-5CqNOR\bower.json

Additional error details:
Unexpected token @ in JSON at position 0
```

Can someone please help me if they have faced this issue before? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Bootstrap v4 no longer supports Bower, apparently; here's the contents of the Bootstrap's bower.json file: "@$% Not a Bower package. Use a better package management tool instead. ^&*"

Comment: Is Yarn supported by Bootstrap v4?

Comment: Basically, yes. Bootstrap can be installed as an NPM package, and yarn reads from the npm repository

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bootstrap v4 will no longer be installable via Bower ([related GitHub pull request](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/23568)); instead, install it with Yarn or NPM.

```
# With NPM
$ npm install --save bootstrap@v4.0.0-beta.2

# With Yarn
$ yarn add bootstrap@v4.0.0-beta.2
```